# How do I Display PostgreSQL/PLPGSQL Error Detail

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How do I go about adding the system generated error detail to RAISE NOTICE statements? For example, I receive an error related to return table structure. SQLERRM simply says 'structure not as expected'. However, if I turn off exception handling and look at the system generated error message it includes additional detail of 'column bigint not as expected int'. Is there a way to get that additional line so that I can add it to my RAISE NOTICE statement?

Current usage:
`RAISE NOTICE '%', SQLERRM;`

Expected:
`RAISE NOTICE '% %', SQLERRM, SQLDET(?);`

I have looked at the PostgreSQL documentation, but that all seems related to if I'd like to add my own commentary - what I'm looking for here is using that which seems to already exist somewhere in the system.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS in your exception handler to get more detail.  The various options are [shown here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS-VALUES).  I'm not certain which one is the one you are looking for, but you should probably try PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL.

Comment: Perfect. Spot on about PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Jake, please, close the question

Comment: @PavelStehule Not sure what you mean - it’s been marked as answered since yesterday.